# PHP mongodb new driver slice(init,limit) nested array

Tags: php, mongodb, limit, slice, database

I have this collection in MongoDB

```
{"name": "x", password: "x" recipes: 
[{title: eggs, ...},{title: "pizza" ...}], name: "y", password: "y" recipes: [...]}
```

I am working with the new php mongodriver 1.0

I would like get all recipes of users filters or not.
but with one limit and init.

for example show  2 recipes starting for 3º recipe:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

show

```
[3,4]
```

I was trying with this

```
$recipes= $db->users->find([],
    [
        "projection"=> ['recipes'=> ['$slice' => [3,2]]]
    ]);
```

but does not work.

however this work limiting the recipes to show but whitout begin filter

```
$recipes= $db->users->find([],
        [
            "projection"=> ['recipes'=> ['$slice' => 2]]
        ]);
```

this show some like this

```
[0,1] of [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$recipes = db->users->find(array(), array('recipes' => array( '$slice' => [3,2] ) ) );
```

Mongo shell:

```
db.users.find( {}, { recipes: { $slice: [3,2] } } );
```